# How to disable Nvidia graphic card on Manjaro Linux?

Tags: linux, nvidia, graphics, gpu, bios

My laptop is **Dell Inspiron 5501**, with two graphics cards:

- GPU: Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce MX330

OS: **Manjaro Ornara 21 KDE**. I want to disable Nvidia. My BIOS version is 1.4.3. I have no idea why Nvidia is working even if I coding. I found that its temperature is 45*C. I’ve try to find something in BIOS, but this new version is so confusing. Can you help me to disable Nvidia and make Intel as primary?

Answer (score 0):

**Source**: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-disable-nvidia-device-for-hybrid-graphics-laptops-only/55844

**Excerpt**:

> - Begin with installing bbswitch module for your kernel. There’s one for each kernel version in Manjaro repository.
> - Next you need to create a couple of config files in /etc/modprobe.d directory.  Let’s describe their contents now.
>
>   > /etc/modprobe.d/nouveau.conf:
>
>   ```
>   blacklist nouveau
>   blacklist nvidia
>   ```
>
>   … and …
>
>   > /etc/modprobe.d/bbswitch.conf:
>
>   ```
>   options bbswitch load_state=0 unload_state=0
>   ```
> - Make sure that other files in this directory do not contain something opposing the above parameters and reboot. It’s that simple.